# Convert PHP 7 Error object to Exception?

Tags: php, exception, php-7

Our years of PHP code has been heavily using Exception handling by converting traditional errors to Exceptions via set_error_handler() and set_exception_handler(). After migrating to PHP 7 for some of our servers errors like this started pumping out:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DataStellar\General\Exception_Handler::getContext() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given
```

We can use \Throwable as type hint but most of our code bases are still on PHP 5 servers.

Is there any way we can easily convert an Error object to an Exception object here?

Comment: upgrade your servers, or downgrade your php version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop the type hinting from the method's definition and use `get_class()` or `instanceof` to decide what to do.

```
class Exception_Handler
{
    public static function getContext($error)
    {
        if (class_exists('\\Error') && $error instanceof \Error) {
            // PHP 7 Error class
            // handle and return
        }

        if ($error instanceof \Exception) {
            // PHP Exception class (user exception in PHP7)
            // handle and return
        }

        // weird edge case
    }
}
```

Comment: But are Error objects and Exception objects inter-changeable in terms of interface? Same methods and properties?

Comment: Yes, both implement \Throwable, just that in PHP7 you don't get errors, you just get Error objects: http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php && http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

Comment: In effect, `\Throwable` is the new exception base class.